# Alter part of Symfony Configuration TreeBuilder

Tags: symfony, symfony-config-component

I have a parent configuration specification

`GenericDatabaseAdapterConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface`

It has some default values - host, user and password. Then there are children that have their specific configuration options.

`MySQLDatabaseAdapterConfiguration extends GenericDatabaseAdapterConfiguration`

It has `charset` option, that `MSSQLDatabaseAdapterConfiguration` does not have.

What would be a good way to alter the existing `TreeBuilder` that is returned from `GenericDatabaseAdapterConfiguration::getConfigTreeBuilder()`. Ideally I would like something like `parent::getConfigTreeBuilder()->appendTo('parameters', $mssqlCustomSettingsNode);`, but that does not exist.

So far I created extension points inside the Generic class. `$this->append($this->getSshTunnelConnectionParametersNode())` is called inside the tree and empty method `getSshTunnelConnectionParametersNode` is inside the generic class that can be overridden in children. But that is not ideal as I need to anticipate every possible point of extension in the Generic class.

Is there a better way?

Comment: For inspiration - completely different approach to config/param inheritance: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/11/29/how-to-manage-configuration-in-symfony-without-bundle-extension-and-configuraiton
I use it for all CLI applications in Symplify and 2 Symfony projects: https://github.com/tomasvotruba/open-project

Comment: The question is unfortunately not at all connected to Symfony applications. We're using configuration from SF in a plain PHP projects...

Comment: Wow, that's very creative. I'd love to see such an application and reasons behind it.

Comment: It's Keboola components - miniature docker-wrapped data manipulation apps - based on https://github.com/keboola/php-component, implementation: https://github.com/keboola/http-extractor

Comment: I see, thanks for links!